# Backup mysql databases into self contained files

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a linux system with Mysql contain more than 400 databases,I need to export each databases as a single `*.sql` file.Is it possible to do this with `mysql_dump` or `Mysqlworkbench`.

I have tried `mysql_dump` with `--all-databases` option.but this make a file with all database.it is large in size.

Comment: check this post may fix your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867520/mysqldump-with-db-in-a-separate-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to write a bash script: [<sub>*(Source)*</sub>](http://dev.mensfeld.pl/2013/04/backup-mysql-dump-all-your-mysql-databases-in-separate-files/)

```
#! /bin/bash

TIMESTAMP=$(date +"%F")
BACKUP_DIR="/backup/$TIMESTAMP"
MYSQL_USER="backup"
MYSQL=/usr/bin/mysql
MYSQL_PASSWORD="password"
MYSQLDUMP=/usr/bin/mysqldump

mkdir -p "$BACKUP_DIR/mysql"

databases=`$MYSQL --user=$MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD -e "SHOW DATABASES;" | grep -Ev "(Database|information_schema|performance_schema)"`

for db in $databases; do
  $MYSQLDUMP --force --opt --user=$MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD --databases $db | gzip > "$BACKUP_DIR/mysql/$db.gz"
done
```

For more information, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867520/mysqldump-with-db-in-a-separate-file) similar question.